# Rigorous proof of convergence of sum to a integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, riemann-integration

I wish to prove the following statement rigorously:

Let $g:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function. Then
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^n g\left( \tfrac{t}{n}\right) = \int_0^1 g(r)dr
\end{equation*}

This picture of this proof is obvious but I am trying to prove it with epsilons and delta's and I just can't seem to put all the pieces together.

Could someone please help! Thanks

PS: I should say that the original statement I wished to prove was actually just for $g\in C[0,1]$, but I couldn't see why this would not just hold for more generally riemann integrable functions.

Comment: Which definition of the Riemann integral are you using?

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the definition of Riemann integral based on Riemann sums. If your definition of Riemann integral is via Darboux sums (as presented in Baby Rudin) then the above becomes a significant theorem with a non-trivial proof.

Comment: My definition of the Riemann Integral (as via Baby Rudin) is via Darboux sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that the following definition of Riemann integral is the one you have learnt:

$f:[a,b]\rightarrow{\bf{R}}$ is said to be Riemann integrable with value $I$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that for every partition $P=\{x_{0},...,x_{n}\}$ of $[a,b]$ with $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|x_{i}-x_{i-1}|<\delta$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(c_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})-I\right|<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
where $c_{i}\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$, $i=1,...,n$.

Then for your question, choose positive integer $N$ large enough such that $1/N<\delta$, for all $n\geq N$, set $P_{n}=\{0,1/n,...,(n-1)/n,1\}$, $c_{i}=1/n$, we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}f\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)\dfrac{1}{n}-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\right|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

From Darboux to Riemann sum: Denote $U(f)$ the infimum of the set of all upper sums $U(f,P)$ for $f$ and similar to the $L(f)$. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose a partition $P_{0}$ such that $U(f,P)<U(f)+\epsilon$ and $L(P,f)>L(f)-\epsilon$. Let $\alpha>0$ be such that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|\leq\alpha$. Assume the partition $P_{0}$ consists of $n_{0}$ points, now we take $\delta=\epsilon/(n_{0}\alpha)$. For any partition $P=\{x_{0},...,x_{m}\}$ of $[0,1]$ such that $\|P\|<\delta$, denote $P^{\ast}$ the common partition of $P$ and $P_{0}$, then of course $U(P^{\ast},f)\leq\min\{U(P,f),U(P_{0},f)\}$.

We observe that for any other point $x^{\ast}$ which lies in $P^{\ast}$ but not $P$ must lie in an open interval $(x_{i-1},x_{i})$ where $x_{i-1},x_{i}$ are points of $P$. So for the part of $U(P,f)-U(P^{\ast},f)$ about $x^{\ast}$, denoting $M_{1}=\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x^{\ast}]}|f(x)|$, $M_{2}=\sup_{x\in[x^{\ast},x]}|f(x)|$ we have 
\begin{align*}
& M_{i}(f)(x_{i}-x_{i-1})-M_{1}(x^{\ast}-x_{i-1})-M_{2}(x_{i}-x^{\ast})\\
&=(M_{i}(f)-M_{1})(x^{\ast}-x_{i-1})+(M_{i}(f)-M_{2})(x_{i}-x^{\ast})\\
&\leq 2\alpha[(x^{\ast}-x_{i-1})+(x_{i}-x^{\ast})]\\
&\leq 2\alpha\|P\|,
\end{align*} 
since the total number of points in the partition $P_{0}$ is $n_{0}$, we have $U(P,f)-U(P^{\ast},f)\leq n_{0}\cdot 2\alpha\|P\|<\epsilon$.

The rest is easy since the Riemann sum $S(P,f)\leq U(P,f)<U(P^{\ast},f)+\epsilon<U(P_{0},f)+\epsilon<U(f)+2\epsilon$ and we can do similar estimation for $L(P,f)$.

Comment: Hrmm I can totally see how via the definition of the Riemann Integral (as the limit of Riemann sums) this becomes a very simple/trivial calculation. Could you possibly shed some light on how to prove it if I was to define the Riemann Integral (as per Baby Rudin) via Darboux Sums? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply!!